# Was Baron Vladimir Harkonnen the only person in the Dune series with a flying suit?

Tags: dune

[Baron Harkonnen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Harkonnen) was so overweight that he requires anti-gravity devices known as suspensors to support his weight.

**Did anybody else have suspensors to help them float or fly?**

Such technology would have helped people out in the deserts to evade sand worms. It would also have helped the Harkonnen soldiers when the [Fremen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fremen) attacked. Looks like the Harkonnen family did not equip their own soldiers with such useful technology.

If the Baron's nephew, [Feyd Rautha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feyd-Rautha), had floating technology, he might have fared better in his duel against [Paul Atreides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Atreides).

Despite the practical uses of personal suspensors for combat and survival, I don't recall seeing the technology used by anyone else.

I have not read the Dune series in decades, so I can't recall if anybody else had a flying suit. Please provide answers based more on the books than the movie or the TV series.

Comment: "Flying suit" is a bit of a misnomer here. In the books, Baron Harkonnen uses the antigravity suit to hold up his enormous weight as he walks around, not to fly around the room.

Comment: In the film there is a scene were he does just that, it's not in the book you are correct. There is a mention that Rabban will need to use a repulsor suit like his uncle when he is older and fatter, I can't quite it now the book is in storage.

Comment: The scene is included in this brief YouTube clip.https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=y09OfBYob7k

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the original Dune, we see the Sardaukar using them instead of rappelling gear *within the confines of the Shield Wall.*

> **A rain of blue uniforms came over the cliff wall in front of him,
>   falling in low-suspensor slowness.** In the flashing instant, Hawat had
>   time to see that they were Sardaukar, hard faces set in battle frenzy,
>   that they were unshielded and each carried a knife in one hand, a
>   stunner in the other.

Jessica posits that because they're based on the same tech as shields, that they may attract worms in the same way and hence be next to useless in the desert.

> If only we had suspensors, Jessica thought. It’d be such a simple
>   matter to jump down there. But **perhaps suspensors are another thing to
>   avoid in the open desert. Maybe they attract the worms the way a
>   shield does.**

A quick glance at the glossary shows her to be right.

> **SUSPENSOR:** *secondary (low-drain) phase of a Holtzman field generator. It nullifies gravity within certain limits prescribed by
>   relative mass and energy consumption.*

Comment: So the emperor's soldiers had suspensors for combat, but the Harkonnen soldiers did not?

Comment: @RichS - Don't forget that the Harkonnen soldiers are used to fighting on Dune, where soldiers wearing suspensors is a massive risk.